# Explanation for difference between Ad Report.csv and /stats/ API data for actions field

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, ads

Have observed an unexpected difference between /stats/ Ads API call and the corresponding line from a manually downloaded Ad Report.csv file.

The Ads API JSON packet includes a null value for "actions" field, but the CSV reports a numeric "2".

The JSON packet is

```
[id] => ___
[impressions] => 10
[clicks] => 1
[spent] => 5
[social_impressions] => 10
[social_clicks] => 1
[social_spent] => 5
[unique_impressions] => 10
[social_unique_impressions] => 10
[unique_clicks] => 1
[social_unique_clicks] => 1
[actions] => 
[connections] => 0
[adgroup_id] => ___
[campaign_id] => ___
[start_time] => 2012-11-10T16:00:00+0000
[end_time] => 2012-11-11T16:00:00+0000
[newsfeed_position] => stdClass Object
    (
        [newsfeed_impressions] => 10
        [newsfeed_clicks] => 1
        [newsfeed_average_position] => 20.8
    )
```

Strangely, all other CSV fields match.

I've included the adgroup structure (ID fields removed)

```
[adgroup_status] => 1
[bid_type] => 1
[max_bid] => 45
[bid_info] => [1 => 45 ]
[ad_status] => 1
[locations] => [0 => 3 ]
[impression_control_map] => Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [location] => 3
        [control] => stdClass Object
        (
            [impression_control_type] => 2
            [user_impression_limit] => 6
            [user_impression_limit_period] => 24
            [user_impression_limit_period_unit] => 0
        )
    )
)
[creative_ids] => Array ( [0] => ___ )
[targeting] => stdClass Object
(
    [genders] => Array ( [0] => 1 )
    [age_max] => 29
    [age_min] => 27
    [countries] => Array ( [0] => IE )
    [page_types] => Array ( [0] => feed )
)
[conversion_specs] => Array ( )
[start_time] => 
[end_time] => 
[updated_time] => 2012-11-08T12:44:09+0000
[created_time] => 2012-11-08T12:43:31+0000
```

Has anyone come across this difference?
Is there a simple explanation?

----- UPDATE 29-Noc-2012  -----

After tracking a number of day's activity on over 2000 adgroup entries, the 'actions' field as returned from the FB Ads API consistently appears empty.

Again, it would be nice to know if this is an observed phenomenon, or if not, means I need to revisit the basics.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can finally answer the first "mystery" - the reason for the null 'actions' field is that the campaign carries and incorrect "bid_info" setting to specify Actions - ie. numeric value 55, as per lined docs.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/conversion-specs/